# Is it possble to reset Spring-Test's context cache before a test suite runs (not after)

Tags: spring-test

We use spring-test (4.x) with junit.  Is it possible to reset spring-test's context cache *before* a test suite runs (not after).

@DirtiesContext only seems to have options to reset the context after execution. We'd like a way to signal spring-test that a specific test suite should be run with a fresh non-cached context (so that we can easily override bean definitions in our tests).  Whether this is an extension to @DirtiesContext or a new annotation such as @RunWithFreshContext doesn't matter as long as we can do so :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

As of Spring Framework 4.2, it will be possible to use `@DirtiesContext` to close a test `ApplicationContext` before a test class or test method. See JIRA issue [SPR-12429](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12429) for details.

---

No, as of Spring Framework 4.1.2, it is not currently possible to have the Spring TestContext Framework remove an `ApplicationContext` from the cache *before* the execution of a test method or test class.

However, it is possible to develop your own custom `TestExecutionListener` that does this for you. For example, you could extend `DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener` and execute its `dirtyContext(...)` method in the `beforeTestClass(...)` and `beforeTestMethod(...)` methods as you see fit. Naturally, if you include your custom TestExecutionListener alongside `DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener`, you wouldn't want your custom listener to perform the same actions of `afterTestMethod(...)` and `afterTestClass(...)` from `DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener`. So you might opt to override those two methods with no-ops or alternatively forgo declaration of the `DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener` in favor of your custom extension.

Regards,

Sam (component lead for `spring-test`)

Comment: Thanks Sam.  I had some more thoughts on this - what would be the most useful scenario would be where we could state that a single test suite did not use a cached context and had a fresh context created, but left the cached context intact for other test suites (so as not to hurt performance too much for the other test suites that could leverage the cached context).

Comment: @user2591854, if you would like such a "throw-away context" feature, please create a JIRA issue requesting it. Thanks. -Sam

Comment: Wonderful idea, atm we have to @DirtyContext every other test because of few tests with different context configuration, and it becomes unhandlable long. Id vote for that issue if it already exists

Comment: @ametiste, to my knowledge there is no existing issue requesting a "throw-away context" in `spring-test`. So feel free to [create a new issue](https://jira.spring.io/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa) requesting this feature and assign it to the "Test" component.

Comment: Has this issue been created? If not, I'll create one.